# Как определить, когда блок закрепился?

Tags: javascript, html

речь о .block

суть - как доскролили - поменять цвет (как пример)
с оранжевого на зеленый

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

header+section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>header</p>
</header>

<section>
  0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur harum, qui labore, dolor mollitia magnam modi illum recusandae voluptate deserunt, in ipsum, corporis adipisci! Minus deleniti, numquam nobis cumque ratione?
</section>

<p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p class="block">Закреплящий блок (блок переходов)</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое (но не самое изящное) решение - прослушивать событие `scroll`, и выставлять элементу класс по условию определенной позиции относительно вьюпорта:

```js
const block = document.querySelector('.block');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const { top } = block.getBoundingClientRect();
  block.classList.toggle('is-fixed', top === 50); 
});
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

header+section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.block.is-fixed { background-color: lime; }
```

```html
<header>
  <p>header</p>
</header>

<section>
  0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur harum, qui labore, dolor mollitia magnam modi illum recusandae voluptate deserunt, in ipsum, corporis adipisci! Minus deleniti, numquam nobis cumque ratione?
</section>

<p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p class="block">Закреплящий блок (блок переходов)</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>
```

Здесь условием является значение верхней координаты элемента - оно становится `50` когда блок "прилипает" (это высота `header`'а, по сути, хоть и заданная стилевым свойством `top` самого блока).

---

Недостатки такого решения:

- критерий изменения класса приходится хардкодить (то есть, "приколачивать гвоздями" к коду и стилям), самостоятельно он не подстраивается под внешние условия.
  *// можно сверять координату с `getComputedStyle(block).top` вместо константы `50`, но это по-прежнему хардкод значения (пусть и только в стилях, при таком варианте)*
- высокая нагрузка на железо, т.к. событие скролла при прокрутке возникает *очень* часто (и код обработчика выполняется огромное количество раз, напрягая процессор). Критично для мобильных устройств.
  *// в целом решается применением паттерна кода [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27078285) (ограничением частоты вызовов обработчика по заданному интервалу времени), но он естественно усложняет решение*

Comment: спасибо, а есть еще вариант? вроде ж только прослушивать событие scroll

Comment: @flowers, сейчас мне в голову пришел только этот вариант. Подождем других ответов :) Вдруг возможно одними стилями решить задачу (согласен, маловероятно, но CSS иногда удивляет)...

Comment: еще раз спасибо огромное) ответ отмечен

Comment: @flowers, вот другое (весьма сложное) решение: [реализация кастомного события 'sticky-change' через `IntersectionObserver`, как альтернатива прослушиванию `scroll`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers) (англ.).

Answer (score 3):

Для таких целей надо использовать IntersectionObserver, а не scroll ивент. Код очень прост. Меняем цвет как только элемент с классом sentinal уйдет на 1 пиксель с области видимости.

```js
const stickyBlock = document.querySelector('.block');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => stickyBlock.classList.toggle('sticked', entry.intersectionRatio !== 1));

observer.observe(stickyBlock.querySelector('.sentinal'));
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

header+section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.sentinal {
  top: -51px; /* на один пиксель больше чем значение top в block */
  position: absolute;
}

.block {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.sticked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>header</p>
</header>

<section>
  0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur harum, qui labore, dolor mollitia magnam modi illum recusandae voluptate deserunt, in ipsum, corporis adipisci! Minus deleniti, numquam nobis cumque ratione?
</section>

<p>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p class="block"><span class="sentinal"></span>Закреплящий блок (блок переходов)</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis soluta placeat, ut totam accusantium. Quam quidem, soluta autem accusamus dolores, quibusdam assumenda architecto neque doloribus esse beatae. Perferendis, quos, eum!</p>
```

Comment: Супер! В статье из блога гугла этот вариант как-то переусложнен, а тут вполне кратко и понятно.