# Как при прокрутке страницы с элементом position: fixed менять цвет fill

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть элемент который расположен в body. На странице есть много блоков и они чередуются цветом, то синий то белый. Как сделать, чтобы когда окошко сообщения переходило на белый цвет, оно менялось на синий, а когда на синий блок переходила, то менялось обратно на белый.
Пытался прикрепить к цвету фона, но не получается, так как родитель всегда body

Comment: Посмотри [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1303727/288409) - думаю что тот же самый подход (использование `IntersectionObserver`) можно применить и в данном случае.

Comment: Данный способ можно использовать с position:fixed или только с sticky?

Comment: Его можно использовать независимо от стилей, т.е. без разницы какое значение `position` (учитываются фактические координаты элемента).

Comment: Спасибо) А можете еще подсказать, как узнать расположение элемента с position:fixed  от самого верха страницы а не от видимого окна

Comment: `element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY` - неважно, какая позиция